# JavaScript prototype problem

Tags: javascript

If I call `myRobot.Speak.sayHi()` it always returns `undefined`. Please, what am I doing wrong? Thanks for reply!

```
var Factory = (function() {

    // Constructor  
    var Robot = function() {

    };

    // Public
    return {
        extendRobot: function(power, methods) {
            Robot.prototype[power] = methods;
        },
        createRobot: function() {
            return new Robot();
        }
    };

}());

Factory.extendRobot('Speak', {
    sayHi: function() {
        return 'Hi, ' + this.name;
    }
});

var myRobot = Factory.createRobot();
myRobot.name = 'Robin';
myRobot.Speak.sayHi() // => ‘Hi, Robin’
```

Comment: You don't return anything so the method returns `undefined`. That's not a problem at all in this case.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Fixed... Still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
createRobot: function() {
    var r = new Robot();
    for (var k in r.Speak) {
        if (typeof r.Speak[k] === "function") {
            r.Speak[k] = r.speak[k].bind(r);
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Rather then returning a new robot, make sure to bind all the methods in your powers to the robot.

To avoid hard coding in the loops try this:

```
Robot.powers = [];
...
extendRobot: function(power, methods) {
    Robot.powers.push(power);
    Robot.prototype[power] = methods;
},
createRobot: function() {
    var robot = new Robot();
    Robot.powers.forEach(function(power) {
        for (var method in robot[power]) {
            if (typeof robot[power][method] === "function") {
                robot[power][method] = robot[power][method].bind(robot);
            }
        }
    });
    return robot;
}
```

This relies on [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) so use the [ES5 shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) or use [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) for supporting old browsers (IE<9)

Answer (score 2):

`myRobot.Speak.name = 'Robin';`

In your case, `this` refers to `Robot.Speak`, not the parent object `Robot`.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Should I use `apply` or `call`?

Comment: But... I would like to access variable `myRobot.name` from `myRobot.Speak.sayHi`. :-| Is it even possible?

Comment: @Emmitt: Yes, it's possible, but it may make your code a little more complex.

Answer (score 0):

insert `name : this.name` before the line `sayHi: function() {` and then it should work

Comment: No it won't, because `this.name` will refer to `Factory.name` when calling `Factory.extendRobot`

Comment: @chomp: No, it won't; it will refer to `window.name`.